# Fixed table header with vertical and horizontal scrollbar using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using jasper report which gives an output in tabular format. There is around 16 column for which I need to fix the table header while scrolling vertically and horizontally. Can anyone help by providing the solution with pure JavaScript only with no Jquery plugin to use?

Comment: apply header: fixed css to the table header? document.getElementById('Table_header').style.position = 'fixed'

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy you can create vertical and horizontal scrollbar by using `scroll` attribute example are as below :

```js
$('table').on('scroll', function() {
  $("table > *").width($("table").width() + $("table").scrollLeft());
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 25px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: block;
}

thead {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

thead,
tbody {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 140px;
}

td,
th {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
      <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
      <td>Row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
      <td>Row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
      <td>Row 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
      <td>Row 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
      <td>Row 10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks SantoshK for your quick response.This is a perfect answer for the above question. But can we some other example where we need not to convert thead and tbody to block as sometime it  does not work on report generated dynamically. OR we can have pure JavaScript solution for this

Comment: for complete javascript implementation you can follow this example : https://jsfiddle.net/3vzrunkt/617/

Comment: Dear SantoshK, the block remove the width of the td in thead and tbody then calculating again with the width of window  and assigning back to thead and tbody> td  is not very suitable solution. The link given above again work only custom table not on tables created dynamically like jasper report do. Please if possible to work on pure javascript code that work on all kind of table

Comment: Dear SantoshK, though it has help me a lot but i need for pure JavaScript code to handle  thead and tbody scroll vertically and horizontally . Kindly help me in this.